# How to hide one submenu when click on another

Tags: javascript

I've got simply javascript to toggle submenu. But there's a problem. I just want to see one submenu at once. How can I fix it?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav > li").click(function(){
        $(this).children('.submenu').css("margin-left", "0").toggle();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Look for active ones and hide them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$('.submenu').hide();                 // hide all submenu's
$(this).children('.submenu').show();  // show the one you clicked
```

Comment: How can I hide an element by clicking any other area than that submenu?

Comment: @Darku something like: `$('html').click(function(){ $('.submenu').hide() });` and then adding `event.stopPropagation()` to the code I provided above.

Comment: @Darku I can't really troubleshoot it without knowing what your code looks like, can you make a https://www.jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: @Darku I don't see the html `.click()` handler on your code anywhere

Comment: Look now. But with that... we again can see 2 submenu at once. I'm beginner so don't kill me if sth is wrong.

Comment: @Darku You have the `$('html').click...` inside `$(".nav > li").click`, it shouldnt be. See here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=TmiLApBw

Comment: @Darku You have now missed `$('.submenu').hide();` out of the `$(".nav > li").click...`

Answer (score 0):

First close all the submenu opened, then show only the submenu of the menu clicked: 
Like this

```
$(".nav > li").click(function(){
    ('.submenu').hide();
    $(this).children('.submenu').css("margin-left", "0").show();
});
```